# Cant add a custom calender package

Tags: android, maven, calendar, repository

when i add `compile 'com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0'`
in my gradle.build 
it gives an error : `Error:(23, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0`

thank in advance

Comment: Have you added the jitpack.io dependency ?

Comment: yes i have added them

Comment: Can you post the logcat

Comment: I added this package in my project and there was no issue.

Comment: could u give me the step by step process of adding the package, because when i was looking for build.gradle, there was 2 files of the same name with different content.

Comment: build.gradle(module:app)

Comment: build.gradle(Project:calender) and this was the other one

Comment: You need to add jitpack.io dependency in Top-level build.gradle and package dependency in the App-level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

**First**,you should check your android-studio settings,Do you set a **http proxy**?

**Secondly**,according the tutorial in https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View

**Thirdly**,Would you like download the dependency into your local matchine then dependent into your project？？

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the build.gradle(Project:calender) file

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
```

And this in build.gradle(module:app)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0'
}
```